# Can we take negative step size in Euler's method?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

Thus far we've taken the step size $h$ to be positive, and therefore we've developed solutions to the right of the initial point. Is Euler's method valid if we use a negative step size $h<0$ and develop a solution to the left?

I think it is not possible.How we can explain that it is possible or not?

Thanks.

Comment: There are two things that might be relevant here.  First, you can use the explicit Euler "forward" method, which you probably have in mind, to march "backward" in time from the initial point.  It amounts to solving a revised problem with the time variable reversed.  Second there is an Euler "backward" method which gives an implicit problem to solve for marching forward in time.

Comment: The geometric justification for negative steps is the same as for positive, the method is valid.

Comment: So it means we can take $h=-0.1$ etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the process of computation stays the same when $h<0$; you get a solution to the left of the initial point. An adjustment in error bound formulas may be needed, since they are written under the assumption $h>0$. So, replace $\text{error}\le Ch$ with $\text{error}\le C|h|$.

As hardmath pointed out in a comment, using $h<0$ in Euler's method is  different from using [Backward (aka implicit) Euler method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backward_Euler_method).